# What are the core parts for making an impressive autosuggestion like Quora?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, autocomplete, nlp, autosuggest

I have recently been asked a design question in an interview:

> How do you think the Quora's autosuggestions works?

I tried my best, but I'm not sure I nailed it :/ I drew a diagram sketch with a few Elasticsearch components, digesting the node part of the pipeline which is responsible to the [named-entity recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) (NER) before indexing the data, and synonyms for the token filter.

Can somebody from the field, elaborate more in depth the core components for Quora's search box, including some essential parts of the classification process?

(I would like to get better in this field.)

Examples:

I have entered `Shrek`, and it suggested `Shrek (character)`.

I have entered `einstein`, and it suggested `Albert Einstein (physicist)`.

I have entered `john`, and it suggested many people profiles which start with "John".

Amazingly this retrieval process takes a few milliseconds. That's impressive. How it is done?

Comment: This article provides some starting points: https://medium.com/@mourjo_sen/a-detailed-comparison-between-autocompletion-strategies-in-elasticsearch-66cb9e9c62c4

Comment: But it is time to leave Medium. It has become paywalled.